# Swift Parse Relation on Cell Button Click Error

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I am using a button within a tableview cell to create a relationship between the currently logged in user and the user who is displayed within the tableview cell that has been clicked. I have been able to create the action functionality for this tableview cell button and can confirm that the click is registered because of my log, but the else statement of my Parse save block is being triggered with the value of `nil`. Am I trying to establish this relationship incorrectly with my parse code?

TableView code:

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var userArray : NSMutableArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        loadParseData()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return userArray.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell

        cell.addUserButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.addUserButton.addTarget(self, action: "addUser:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        let users: PFObject = self.userArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        if let user : PFUser = users as? PFUser {
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

            println("user exist")

            if let userImage : PFFile = user["profileImage"] as? PFFile {

                userImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
                    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                    if error != nil {

                        let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!

                        cell.userImage.image = image as UIImage

                    }

                }

            } else {

                cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "profileImagePlaceHolder")

            }

        }
        return cell
    }

    func loadParseData() {

        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects {

                    println("\(objects.count) users are listed")

                    for object in objects {

                        self.userArray.addObject(object)

                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println("There is an error")
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addUser(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("Button Triggered")

        let addUserButton : UIButton = sender as! UIButton

        let user : PFObject = self.userArray.objectAtIndex(addUserButton.tag) as! PFObject

        var relation : PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("Followers")

        relation.addObject(user)

        PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeed:Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {

                println("Added User")

            } else {

                println(error)

            }

        }
    }

}
```

TableView Cell:

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {



    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addUserButton: UIButton!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        userImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        userImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        userImage.layer.cornerRadius = userImage.frame.width/2
        userImage.clipsToBounds = true


    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }



}
```

UPDATE: The data is actually being sent correctly to parse, but I'm not sure why my else statement is firing.

[image: relation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement inside the `PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock` block in `addUser(...)` looks wrong. You're testing if the error is not nil `!=` (i.e., there is an error). Maybe if it was testing for nil as below...

```
if error == nil {
  println("Added User")
} else {
  println(error)
}
```

...you'd see the logging statements that you expect.